# Getting the id value corresponding to the selectedsegment for segmentControl iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

First of all sorry for the title.

I have one segment control in my app.The titles of the segments are fetching from the server and setting accordingly(ie YES and NO).

There is also one corresponding id value for each segment.So when the user select YES a corresponding id 8 is to saved,and when user Select NO a corresponding id 5 is to be saved(8 and 5 are coming from the server).

I tried by setting the tags but in vain.

Can anyone please help me with this scenario.

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
 //Code
     for(WTMobileDataService_DataAccess_ClsYesNo *temp in YesNo)
        {
            NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",temp.m_YesNoDescription];
             ind = [temp.m_PK_YesNoID intValue] - 1;

            [items addObject:s];
            [serverids addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",ind]];

           // [segmentControl setTitle:s forSegmentAtIndex:ind];
        }

segmentControl  = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:items];
```

Comment: Please show us the code you wrote to set the tags.

Comment: @bdesham i deleted that code because it is not working as we can have only one tag for entire segment control

Comment: What's the problem you are having with this new piece of code?

Comment: @bdesham the titles are not coming.can we chat in a room.Please

Comment: That doesn’t really work for me. Why don’t you edit your question some more and I or someone else will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Have two arrays, one with the titles, the other with the values. When the user selects a segment, use the selected segment to return the title, and then use that to get the index of the title. Then you can reference the values array and you've got the corresponding value.

You could also achieve the same thing using an NSDictionary where the title is your key, and the value is... the value.

Something like this:

```
NSArray titles = @[@"YES", @"NO"];
NSArray values = @[8, 5];

UISegmentedControl control; // Likely defined as a property
if ([control selectedSegmentIndex] != UISegmentedControlNoSegment) {
    NSString title = [control titleForSegmentAtIndex:];

    int index = [titles indexOfObject:title];
    NSString value = [values objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since each `UISegmentedControl` has only one tag, you'll need to do something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *serverIds = [NSMutableArray new];

for (ServerResponseObject *response in serverResponses) {
    [items addObject:response.title];
    [serverIds addObject:response.id];
}

mySegmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:items];
```

Thereafter, when the user taps on the `UISegmentedControl`, access the `selectedIndex` property of the segmented control to find out which segment they tapped on, and use this value as the key to the `serverIds` array to see what the corresponding ID number is according to the server.

Comment: i added the uisegmeted control from xib

Comment: im trying like this according to your answer

Comment: @suji If that doesn't work, try editing your question above to show the code you're using. It's hard to read it down here in the comments ;-)

Comment: please see my question.i edited it now.now titles are not coming

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to create an object to hold the two values together as they seem like a natural grouping

```
@interface SegmentInfo : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy)  NSString  *title;
@property (nonatomic, assign NSInteger  value;

- (instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title value:(NSInteger)value;

@end

@implementation SegmentInfo

- (instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title value:(NSInteger)value
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    _title = [title copy];
    _value = value;
  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

Now you populate these objects and store them in an array

```
self.segmentInfos = @[
  [[SegmentInfo alloc] initWithTitle:@"Yes" value:8],
  [[SegmentInfo alloc] initWithTitle:@"No"  value:5],
];
```

To set up the segmented control you just grab all the titles into an array

```
some set up method
{
  NSArray *segmentTitle = [self.segmentInfo valueForKey:@"title"];
  self.segmentControl   = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segmentTitle];
}
```

Now in your method that handles value changes you simple grab the object at the same index and get the value

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControlChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)segmentedControl
{
  SegmentInfo *selectedSegment = self.segmentInfos[segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex];
  NSLog(@"title: %@, value: %d", selectedSegment.title, selectedSegment.value);
}
```